# Representation Theory and Equivariant Stable Homotopy Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, equivariant-cohomology

What is a good book/source to understand Representations of a Group in the sense we use it in Equivariant Stable Homotopy Theory? I've read Barry Simon's book on Representation Theory but would like to be more comfortable with the ideas of Universe, irreducible representations and the like we use in Equivariant Stable Homotopy Theory.

Thanks!!

Comment: You could try tom Dieck's *Transformation Groups and Representation Theory*.

Comment: Okay. Thanks !!